# how to compare listbox items with memo field in a table in foxpro for exact match?

Tags: visual-foxpro

I am having an `Inv` table having `tags` as the field containing memo type, Now how to compare list box items with `Inv.tags`(memo) weather any of the records in `inv.tags` are matching with listbox items , this is the code i have written,

```
Create Cursor mycursor(RecordS c(50))
IFExists=.F.
For nCount = 0 To Thisform.list3.ListCount
    Append Blank
    Replace RecordS With Alltrim(Thisform.list3.List(nCount))
    IFExists=.T.
Endfor
Delete From mycursor Where RecordS==""

lcMessage = ""
select mycursor
scan
    lcMessage = lcMessage + transform(records) + chr(13)
ENDSCAN


lbMessage = ""
select inv
scan
    lbMessage = lbMessage + transform(tags) + chr(13)
ENDSCAN  
IF ALLTRIM(lcMessage) == ALLTRIM(lbMessage)
MESSAGEBOX('Success',64,'Status')
ELSE
MESSAGEBOX('Mis Match',16,'Status')
ENDIF
```

i am getting the result as mismatch even if the records are matching. Thank You!

Comment: If you want to compare concatenations of field values like this then you have to ensure that all incidentals are *exactly* the same: the trim state (i.e. leading/interspersed/trailing blanks), capitalisation and **order**. I.e. cursor/table records must have the same order as the list box entries, and the order of tags within single fields must also be the same. Also, if you dump the strings to the debug output window (`acti wind 'debug output'`, followed by `debugo m.lcMessage` etc. pp.) then you can see for yourself what's wrong instead of posting questions that don't really belong here.

Comment: P.S.: when posing problems with code operating on data then it is helpful to give an example based on data that everyone can access, for example the Northwind or Tastrade sample databases in FoxPro. They are not public domain but every Fox user has at least one of the two, and everyone else can use one of the freely available incarnations of Northwind for e.g. SQL Server (and dump to Fox DBFs if necessary). Also, when transporting your problem to a public dataset like Northwind you'll either find the source of the problems yourself or gain deeper understanding of the problem.

Comment: In other words: **post a reproducible problem**.

Comment: i am new to foxpro and i am looking for some help instead of advices how to post and what needs to be posted , anyways thanks for your valuable advice....

Comment: Reducing a given problem to its essence in order to produce a **minimal, complete and reproducible example** is not easy but it is a valuable skill that will serve you well in all areas of programming and debugging, not only in forums like Stack Overflow. In fact, it is one of the essential prerequisites for becoming a good programmer. From the state of your account it is immediately obvious to everyone that you didn't ven read the introductory help screen when you signed up at Stack Overflow. It tells you how to post successful questions that can get good answers quickly, among other things

Comment: Please stop tagging with both Visual-Foxpro and Foxpro. They are two different products.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it is mismatching, because you start the index of your listbox at 0. In VFP, indexes start at 1 and the listbox control will return an empty string, when referencing "Thisform.list3.List(0)".

Anyways, I could not reproduce the problem either, so this is just a suggestion.